# Nginx - Wrong Response Header

Tags: nginx, http-headers, joomla, http-status-code

when installing joomla I face an issue realated to response header.

During the installation process, an ajax post request send to server which in response status is `303` instead of `200` ! so ajax callback doesn't fire and installtion breaks.

I think this issue is related to nginx config because I test it on apache local server and there is no problem there.

nginx access log :

```
POST /installation/index.php HTTP/1.1" 303 5 "http://.../installation/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
```

apache (local) access log :

```
"POST /joomla-test/installation/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 286
```

nginx config :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_pass_header Status; <-- tested but not work !
        include fastcgi.conf;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 303 is a redirection.

There is nowhere in the configuration snippet you provide which creates any redirection whatsoever. It thus comes from a PHP file being processed in the block you are providing as I trust: you need to check the PHP application to fix this unwished redirection.